# Python how to handle unicode text

Tags: python, unicode

I am using Python 2.6.6

```
item = {u'snippet': {u'title': u'How to Pronounce Canap\xe9'}}
title = item['snippet']['title']
print title
```

Result:

```
How to Pronounce CanapÃ©
```

Desired result:

```
How to Pronounce Canapé
```

This looks like a Unicode issue, I tried encode and decode to utf8, but result still the same, any ideas?

Comment: That code sample works fine in my terminal. I have to assume this is an issue with your OS or terminal. What OS/Terminal software are you using?

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: @BenEchols, OS is CentOS 6.4, Terminal is SecureCRT 4.0

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, on command line I type python, that puts me into the Python shell

Comment: Check the encoding of your SecureCRT session and make sure its UTF8 and not latin-1 or similar.

Comment: what is `locale charmap`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, UTF-8

Comment: what is `sys.stdout.encoding`? Change SecureCRT setting to accept utf-8

Comment: sys.stdout.encoding -> 'UTF-8'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal expects `UTF-8`:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
```

Python prints using `UTF-8`:

```
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8
```

Change SecureCRT setting to accept UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possibly due to mismatch of the default encoding that Python is using versus the console's encoding.  It looks like Python is assuming that the encoding is UTF-8 but then the console is interpreting that as latin-1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\xe9`, use `\u00e9` if possible. Then pick an appropriate encoding when outputting the unicode string:

```
print title.encode('latin1')
```

What encoding is sensible depends on where you are outputting to. Generally, you have to infer it from the environment variables, or maybe let your users make a choice in a configuration file.

PS: If you deal with Unicode strings a lot, I'd recommend switching to Python 3 (e.g. 3.3), if at all possible. Unicode handling is a lot more clear/explicit/sane, there.

Comment: I am not able to change \xe9 to \u00e9, the \xe9 is raw data from YouTube API

Comment: Ok, that shouldn't matter for Python2.7. From the output you've show, I think ``'latin1'`` might be the correct encoding in your case.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger:  `u'\xe9' == u'\u00e9'` therefore changing it won't help. Instead of `.encode('latin1')`, change `SecureCRT` to match the terminal settings on CentOS. If `sys.stdout.encoding` is correct (it matches `$LC_TYPE`, `$LANG`) then using Python 3 won't help

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I am getting the same error when I write the values to a file on the file system, would that indicate the problem is not SecureCRT?

Comment: @davidjhp: Writing to a file is different from writing to a terminal. If the output is redirected to a file, you could control the stdout encoding using `PYTHONIOENCODING`. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22496097/edit) with the output of `print(repr(open("your_output_file", "rb").read()))`?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting your expected output in my terminal (using python 2.7.7)
The format you are expecting depends on encoding set in the terminal. For me, it is set to 'cp437'

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp437'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp437'
```

You can verify that, you are getting correct output by giving:

```
print title.encode('cp437')
```

Answer (score 0):

set your default encoding to `iso-8859-1` in your sitecustomize.py file in `${pythondir}/lib/site-packages/` as

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')
```

for me it worked with `\xe9`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencodi

Comment: @davidjhp: don't do it. Changing `sys.getdefaultencoding()` from `'ascii'` might break other Python scripts on your system in a subtle way.